# Conversão de uma variável com replace para decimal

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo, decimal

Estou com uma pequena dúvida, passo um valor `0,05 decimal` para uma variável `A` do tipo `string`. Depois que essa variável recebe esse valor, faz a conversão de `,` para ponto `.`, que fica `0.05`

Depois que faço esse replace, converto os dados para o tipo `Decimal`, minha variável `B` que recebe a variável `A` fica `inteira 5`.

```
 var openingCostValue = Convert.ToDecimal(model.openingCost.Replace(",", "."));
```

O que quero, é que mantenha o valor que foi convertido no replace.

Comment: Tem como colocar mais código? desde o começo aonde você pega o valor decimal, talvez tenha um modo mais fácil de resolver isso.

Comment: Não tem necessidade

Comment: Então ta, Boa sorte.

Comment: Não precisa fazer o replace, só converter direto. Apenas tome cuidado com questões de internacionalização

Comment: vero sem replace

Comment: @RichardDias, o problema se n fizer o replace, no momento que ele salva no meu banco de dados, se o valor  for com virgula, o SQL server deixa o valor inteiro

Comment: O seu tipo de dados no banco é numérico e no seu código é string?

Comment: Sim, e converto para tipo numérico e envio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A forma correta de fazer isso é uma tentativa de [`parse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Decimal_TryParse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Decimal__) levando em consideração a cultura (existem gambiarras que só funcionará por coincidência). Se tivesse mais informações na pergunta eu poderia dar um exemplo mais específico. Vou dar um exemplo genérico:

```
decimal.TryParse("0,05", NumberStyles.Number, new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), out valor)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6qs1lK). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/779RUT). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Decimal/ParseStyle.cs).

Dado e apresentação é algo diferente. Dependendo do que precisa pode ser que a solução nem seja esta. Respondi o que foi perguntado.

Eventualmente é possível não usar o mecanismo do `try` mas só pode fazer isto se tiver certeza que a conversão será bem sucedida sempre. Se o dado vem externamente, ou de algum componente que não pode garantir isso, não dá para ter certeza.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve utilizar o `replace` se quiser formatar o valor para apresentação para o usuário. Caso contrário só converter direto.

Um caso diferente é se essa string vem o usuário. Por padrão o separador `.` é para decimal e o `,` é para milhares.

Logo `Convert.ToDecimal("0.05");` = 0,05 e `Convert.ToDecimal("0,05");` = 5.

Comment: Então, man. Quando mando o valor, é 0,05. Se eu fizer o Convert.ToDecimal(), ele ficar o valor inteiro (5). Qualquer valor decimal que é passado, sempre será separado por ','. Por isso utilizei o replace.

Answer (score 1):

Seu método está retornando inteiro porque você não definiu a cultura.

O padrão brasileiro é "," 
Logo, se você passar "." a função não irá reconhecer e retornará 5

Exemplos:

`var valor = decimal.Parse("0,05", new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));` Retorno: `0.05`

`var valor = decimal.Parse("0.05", new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));` Retorno: `5`

No seu código, basta você não usar o `Replace`

`var openingCostValue = Convert.ToDecimal(model.openingCost);` saída será `0.05`

Caso você queira a saída com vírgula

```
var openingCostValue = Convert.ToDecimal(model.openingCost).ToString().Replace(".", ",");
```