# Variável com valor não atribuído dentro de um laço "for"

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, for, loop

```
    int i;
    string cpf;
    cpf = "11111111111";
    DbConnection cnx = ADO_Utils.GetConnection();
    DbCommand cmd = ADO_Utils.GetComando(cnx);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    for (i = 1; i < Convert.ToInt32(txbQtde.Text); i++) ;
    {
        string query;
        query = "insert into tblAcordoParcel (txtCPF, intParcela, dblValorParcel, dtVencimento, blnBaixada) ";
        query = query + "Values (  " + "'" + cpf + "',";
        query = query + i + ",";
        query = query + "" + txbParcel.Text + ",";
        query = query + "'" + txbDt.Text + "',";
        query = query + "0"+ ")";
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

Ao executar esse código, a variável `i` assume o valor digitado na tela e não o número 1 que eu declarei dentro do `for`.

Comment: Nunca fiz nada usando C# então tenho algumas dúvidas sobre seu código: existe um `;` na frente da linha do comando `for`, acredito que esteja errado; você cria uma variável `int` mas compara com uma variável `int32` (`Convert.ToInt32(txbQtde.Text)`) e depois concatena ela com uma `string`, do meu ponto de vista tem algo bem errado nisso.

Apesar disso, creio que o problema seja o `;` na linha do seu comando `for`

Comment: @Gerep `int` é alias de `Int32`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro é que o `for` não está sendo executado, ele está sendo encerrado antes mesmo de iniciar, afinal logo no início dele já há um `;` que o encerra. O correto seria ter um bloco de comandos em seguida, assim:

```
var cpf = "11111111111"; //se não for só um teste não precisa da variável
DbConnection cnx = ADO_Utils.GetConnection();
DbCommand cmd = ADO_Utils.GetComando(cnx);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
for (var i = 1; i < Convert.ToInt32(txbQtde.Text); i++) { // <==== note que não tem o ;
    cmd.CommandText = @"insert into tblAcordoParcel (txtCPF, intParcela, dblValorParcel, 
dtVencimento, blnBaixada) Values (@cpf, @i, @parcel, @dt, 0)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpf", cpf);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", i);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parcel", txbParcel.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", txbDt.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/Insert.cs).

Note que eu fiz alguma mudanças.

Retirei a exceção porque ela não estava fazendo nada útil. [Se não tem algo útil para fazer com a exceção, não a capture](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101%20[exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o]).

Simplifiquei colocando a declaração e atribuição na mesma linha, não existe motivo para fazer em linhas separadas. Em alguns casos usei o [`var`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101) que simplifica também.

E principalmente usei o comando certo para montar a *query* de forma segura. O que estava sendo feito era uma temeridade.

[Usar um tipo `double` para valor monetário é outra temeridade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101).

Tem outras coisas que parecem esquisitas, mas como não estou vendo o todo não vou me pronunciar. Um deles é o uso de [notação húngara](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139321/101) nos nomes das colunas. Tem outros.

Se os tipos de `dblValorParcel` e `dtVencimento` são numérico e data, provavelmente precise fazer uma conversão antes de usá-lo, já que o que vem de fora vem como `string`. Se alguma conversão der errado por alguma razão (um texto que não produz um número, por exemplo), haverá uma exceção e será um erro de programação. Isto vale até para o `Convert` já existente. O ideal seria tratar isto de outra forma e evitar a exceção, mas é outro assunto.

Comment: Obrigado por utilizar varias a palavra temeridade... Mostra que vc se comprometeu em responder da melhor forma pra eu aprendesse. Valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: Obrigado por compreender isto. Tem gente que adora ver problemas nos outros. Isto mostra maturidade sua. Eu não poderia classificar de outra forma. Se todo mundo fosse como você, este site seria uma maravilha. O problema não é não saber, todos aqui não sabem quase nada de tudo, o problema é quando a pessoa não quer aprender e prefere ficar de mimimi. Parabéns.

Comment: O mundo todo anda mimizento demais mesmo.... Mas temeridades a parte quando tenho que passar valores com centavos da erro como insiro esses valores no Insert sem a virgula???

Comment: Fazendo a conversão para valor. Enquanto tiver usando um `double` tem que converter para este tipo, de preferência ["tentar converter"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16203/101). Claro que se tiver certeza que a conversão será bem sucedida (não tem chance de ter uma valor inválido naquela *string*, aí pode fazer o mais simples, pode até usar o [`Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que você já sabe usar. Exemplo que depende de formato: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106672/101,

Comment: Deu certo tanto o for quanto o valor monetário... Obrigado... Tem algum artigo ou mesmo resposta aqui no flow que mostra como criar documento PDF tipo recibo ou declaração???

Comment: Desconheço especificamente. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+pdf

Comment: Dentro desse mesmo FOR preciso que a cada passo da Variavel i seja acrescentado 30 dias no txbDt.Text, preciso usar outro for ou tem outra maneira de fazer??

Comment: Não, Você está enfileirando várias perguntas na mesma. Cada dúvida precisa ser um pergunta nova pra ficar organizado e poder facilitar a busca de outra pessoas.

Comment: pergunta feita.... obrigado pela orientação