# Acrescentar dias na data crescentes via For

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, for

No código abaixo eu adiciono 1 a cada passo na variável `i`, para acrescentar 30 dias no campo `dt`, preciso de outro `for` ou da pra fazer nesse mesmo?

```
DbConnection cnx = ADO_Utils.GetConnection();
DbCommand cmd = ADO_Utils.GetComando(cnx);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
for (var i = 1; i < Convert.ToInt32(txbQtde.Text); i++) { // <==== note que não tem o ;
    cmd.CommandText = @"insert into tblAcordoParcel (txtCPF, intParcela, dblValorParcel, 
dtVencimento, blnBaixada) Values (@cpf, @i, @parcel, @dt, 0)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpf", cpf);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", i);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parcel", txbParcel.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", txbDt.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: A solução é simples para para dar uma resposta completa e correta eu precisa saber qual é o tipo da coluna `dtVencimento`.?

Comment: nesse momento string, mas se for mais fácil eu sei como mudar para datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, está pegando um texto e precisa fazer uma conversão para data, pelo menos para facilitar. Depois basta somar 30 trinta dias na data a cada passo, é pura matemática, `i * 30`. Se em vez de ser 30 dias for 1 mês (são coisas diferentes), dá para fazer também. O ideal é guardar datas em formato adequado. Se quer manter a coluna como `character`, pode fazer a conversão de novo para este tipo.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", Convert.ToDateTime(txbDt.Text).AddDays(i * 30).ToString());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/AddDateSpecific.cs).

Note que é preciso garantir que a data sempre estará em formato correto, caso contrário deve cuidar disto antes. Como eu disse na [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124601/101).

Não posso garantir que é exatamente o que precisa porque a pergunta não dá tantos detalhes, mas é basicamente isto. Talvez precise fazer alguma adaptação. Pode ser que o formato gerado pelo `ToString()` não seja adequado ao que precisa e tenha que escolher um formato próprio. Ou ainda seja mais interessante trocar o tipo da coluna.

Também precisa analisar se este é o algoritmo mais correto. Parece que ele tenta estabelecer os vencimentos de parcelas. Tenho minhas dúvidas que essa deva ser a estratégia. Pode ser uma forma ingênua de fazer isto, mas não posso afirmar nada. Cada empresa tem um jeito de trabalhar.